# Can I combine Conv2D and LeakyReLU into a single layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The keras Conv2D layer does not come with an activation function itself. I am currently rebuilding the YOLOv1 model for practicing. In the YOLOv1 model, there are several Conv2D layers followed by activations using the leaky relu function. Is there a way to combine

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, LeakyReLU

...

def model(input):
    ...

    X = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size)(X)
    X = LeakyReLU(X)

    ...
```

into a single line of code, like `X = conv_with_leaky_relu(X)`? I think it should be similar to

```
def conv_with_leaky_relu(*args, **kwargs):
    X = Conv2D(*args, **kwargs)(X)
    X = LeakyReLU(X)
    return X
```

but this of course doesn't work because it is undefined what X ist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just pass it as an activation:

```py
X = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation=LeakyReLU())(X)
```

Comment: Didn't know that, just looked at the list of activations implemented and leaky relu didn't appear to be part of that list. Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @sampleuser - you can pass callable objects to `activation` in addition to strings